# Telephone with OpenTok

Tags: android, ios, opentok, tokbox

We are developing a VoIP app and we want to switch to the **Tokbox** library.

Ours is like a telephone app just like **Viber** but for a specific audience. We need the app to behave like a telephone app. The user makes the call, the receiver hears the phone ringing, picks up the call and hangs it up when done talking. I could find a lot of resources on **Tokbox** online (for Android and iOS) but I couldn't find much info on a telephone with the library. Can anyone point me to the right direction or explain things a little bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

To implement a mobile telephony app (like Viber) where user A calls user B you need a couple of extra pieces in addition to TokBox platform.

First you need to make use of standard Apple&Google push notifications to initiate the call to B.  For example you can use Google's service [1].  Typically A will send a HTTP request to your server to initiate the call to B and your server will use Google API to send the push notification to B.

At the same time your server should generate a TokBox sessionId for this call and send that sessionId and a token back to user A.  User A can use them to connect to the TokBox session and start publishing while waiting for B to join it.

When B receives the notification then you can alert the user (ringing tone) and present any UI you want to him.  When B accepts the call you can make another HTTP request to your server to get the sessionId and token for the call (that sessionnId and token could also come in the initial push notification) and join it.

At that point you have both users (A and B) connected to the same TokBox session, publishing audio&video and subscribing to the other stream, so you have a bidirectional audio+video call.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/